# How to enable active learning for LUIS app - botvuilder SDK JavaScript V4

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to enable the active learning for our LUIS app connected to a chatbot.

According to LUIS docs, I found out that we should add `log=true` to LUIS endpoint URL.

For that, the botbuilder SDK offers the **LuisRecognizer** class that allows us create a Luis Instance fort the bot.

I checked out the botbuilder SDK V4 for JavaScript and I did not find how the add log=true to the endpoint URL!

```
const dispatchRecognizer = new LuisRecognizer(
  {
    applicationId: luisConfig.appId,
    endpointKey: luisConfig.subscriptionKey,
    endpoint: luisConfig.getEndpoint()
  },
  {
    staging: true
    includeAllIntents: true,
    includeInstanceData: true
  },
  true
);
```

Is there a wait to resolve the issue this or to pass the luis URL directly to the class constructor?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-ai/src/luisRecognizer.ts#L88) that it's part of `LuisPredictionOptions`:

```js
export interface LuisPredictionOptions extends LuisModels.PredictionResolveOptionalParams {
    bingSpellCheckSubscriptionKey?: string;
    includeAllIntents?: boolean;
    includeInstanceData?: boolean;
    log?: boolean; // SET TO TRUE
    spellCheck?: boolean;
    staging?: boolean;
    timezoneOffset?: number;
    telemetryClient?: BotTelemetryClient;
    logPersonalInformation?: boolean;
}
```

You're already passing in `LuisPredictionOptions`, you just need to edit it so you're doing it like this:

```js
const dispatchRecognizer = new LuisRecognizer(
  {
    applicationId: luisConfig.appId,
    endpointKey: luisConfig.subscriptionKey,
    endpoint: luisConfig.getEndpoint()
  },
  {
    log: true,
    staging: true
    includeAllIntents: true,
    includeInstanceData: true
  },
  true
);
```